# Using Tor over IPv6

Tags: configuration, torsocks, ipv6

Can someone explain what I have to configure to get tor working over ipv6 on client-side?

```
$ torify telnet -6 www.google.com 80
telnet: could not resolve www.google.com/80: Non-recoverable failure in name resolution

$ torify telnet -6 2a00:1450:4001:811::2004 80
Trying 2a00:1450:4001:811::2004...
1621180047 PERROR torsocks[2621]: socks5 libc connect: Invalid argument (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Both tor and torsocks should support IPv6. Can you include the output of `torsocks --version` and `tor --version`?

Comment: Looks like a problem with torify/torsocks, they fail for me but curl works: `curl -vk --proxy socks5://<tor-proxy>:9050 'https://\[2a00:1450:4001:811::2004\]`